# can rethrow_exception really throw the same exception object, rather than a copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

While examining what `exception_ptr` does, the C++11 standard says (18.8.5/7) that:

> Use of rethrow_exception on exception_ptr objects that refer to the same exception object shall not introduce a data race. [ Note: if rethrow_exception rethrows the same exception object (rather than a copy), concurrent access to that rethrown exception object may introduce a data race...

I don't find the case where this weird "Note" applies, since the described effect of `rethrow_exception` is "Throws: the exception object to which p refers" but 15.1/3, describing the general exception throwing process mandates that "throwing an exception copy-initializes a temporary object, called the exception object."

The weird note would imply that rethrow_exception skips this copy-initialization. But is this really possible?

Comment: Maybe it's just moving?

Comment: Yup, `std::rethrow_exception` cannot be implemented using a `throw x;` expression.  (But it's similar to `throw;`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it looks like a deficiency in the standard.  For a rethrowing throw-expression i.e. `throw;` without an operand, 15.1p8 says:

> A *throw-expression* with no operand rethrows the currently handled exception. The exception is reactivated with the existing exception object; no new exception object is created. [...]

That is:

```
#include <exception>
#include <cassert>
int main() {
   std::exception *p = nullptr;
   try {
      try {
         throw std::exception();
      } catch(std::exception &ex) {
         p = &ex;
         throw;
      }
   } catch(std::exception &ex) {
      assert(p == &ex);
   }
}
```

If the implementation of `current_exception` copies the currently handled exception object, there's no way to tell whether `rethrow_exception` copies or not, but if it refers to the exception object then we can check:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::exception_ptr p;
   try {
      try {
         throw std::exception();
      } catch(...) {
         p = std::current_exception();
         std::cout << (p == std::current_exception()) << ' ';
         std::rethrow_exception(p);
      }
   } catch(...) {
      std::cout << (p == std::current_exception()) << '\n';
   }
}
```

Every implementation I've tried it on prints `1 1`; `0 0` is allowed if `current_exception` copies; `0 1` is obviously impossible, while the standard in its current state appears to require `1 0`.  The fix would be for 18.8.5p10 to be clarified with language similar to 15.1p8, either allowing or mandating `rethrow_exception` to not copy the exception object pointed to by the `exception_ptr`.

Most **Throws:** specifications in the standard just name a type (*Throws: `bad_alloc`*) or use the indefinite article (*Throws: an exception of type ...*); the only other exception specifications to use the definite article are those of `future::get` and `shared_future::get`, so any resolution should probably address those as well.

Comment: After further investigations, I've found an issue of the LWG proposing to mandate a copy in this case (issue #1369). They appear to have settled against it, confirming how implementations seem to behave. I believe a clarification like the one you propose makes sense, though.

Answer (score 4):

When you say `throw x;`, then the exception object has the same type as `x` but is a copy.

When you say `std::rethrow_exception(p);`, the exception object is the actual object which is referred to by the pointer, and no further copies get made.

Thus is several threads concurrently rethrow the *same* exception pointer (which you are allowed to copy!), then they all have a reference to the *same* object.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Still, the standard is confusing when it describes the behavior of rethrow_exception as "Throws: the exception object to which p refers."

Comment: @twicker: I think that's pretty clear. There is always a notion of "the exception object", and `std::current_exception` creates a pointer to that object.

Comment: MSVC copies the exception object into the `exception_ptr` when you call `current_exception`, and copies it *again* when you call `rethrow_exception`: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1675r2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. The exception-handling mechanism already has a copy of the object that was originally thrown, squirreled away in a private memory stash. Typically, `exception_ptr` is implemented as a smart pointer that manages a reference count for that copy.

As to the **general** requirements, if a specific requirement conflicts with a general requirement, the specific requirement wins.

Comment: But AFAIK notes are not normative, so rethrowing should create the mandated new copy.

Comment: @twicker - you may be right that this isn't correctly specified. `<g>` `exception_ptr` was originally a library-only extension, which required extension of the runtime exception support but no language changes. Requiring a new copy would mean requiring a way to store a pointer to the object's copy constructor; while that's technically feasible, it's much simpler to just re-use the old object. And in practice, there's no difference; you might write a copy constructor that records whether it's called, but that aside, it doesn't affect any real-world code.